# Allow access to a user-type custom object

Tags: custom-object, account, authentication, user-record

I have a custom object called 'Advisor' and for every single record, I would like to allow authentication access for that one Advisor to log in and view their record and make changes.

For example, there is an `Advisor_1` record in Advisor, and I would like to allow Advisor_1 to log in and view their own record (but not any other advisor's record). An Advisor is assigned `Tickets` (another custom object) and when an Advisor logs in to sales force they should be able to mark a Ticket as completed.

Is this possible to make a custom object "Authenticatable"? Or can you create a normal salesforce account, but only allow access to certain records within certain objects? I know you can allow access to only certain Objects, but can these permissions extend to records of Objects as well?

Comment: Have you looked at [Record-Level Security](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/data_security/data_security_records)? I think the "authentication" language may be a misnomer here.

Comment: This would be a great starting point, https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/data_security/data_security_records

Comment: @DavidReed so I was able to use that to restrict access, however, I believe the Org-wide sharing setting I need to use on Advisor is `Controlled By Parent` and then add a User field of type Master-Detail Lookup to the Advisor object. The reason you need Master-Detail Lookup relationship is because that is the only way to get a `Controlled By Parent` option when selecting sharing settings. However, when I go to add that type of relationship to Advisor, User is not an option.... Is there a possible way around this?

Comment: @BlondeSwan User cannot be the parent of a master-detail relationship, but that doesn't matter because it isn't what you need. You need an Org-Wide Default of Private, and the User that your Advisor uses to log in (perhaps some type of community license?) needs to own its corresponding Advisor record.

Comment: @BlondeSwan But all of that is dependent upon, as Adrian explained below, creating actual Users, and setting up a Community to support this objective is way beyond the scope of a comment.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to authenticate is as a `User`. If you want a custom `Advisor__c` object which can log in, create a lookup from this object to `User` to indicate who this person can log in as. You can add a `Process Builder` flow to set the `OwnerId` on each `Ticket__c` record to `Advisor__r.User__c`, and it is certainly possible to set up a permission model where these users can only see records they own.

If you want someone to log in to your system, you have to create a `User` record and consume a license. Full stop.